# Rules for ending a chess game

Tags: endgame, rules

I have seen many games that do not end by checkmate but still say 0-1 or 1-0.  The following picture also shows that the game did not end but White won. Can anyone please explain this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means one of the players resigned or lost on time.  In the game above, White threatens mate on g6 if the black Queen can be deflected from its defense. So White threatens `Qxe8` followed by `Qxg6#`.  If Black plays `37... Qf7`, White responds with `Qxd7` which threatens the Black Queen and a potential mate on g7. It's a mess that at best ends up with Black being down a ton of material.

Comment: Why not 37...Nxe5  Anyway, White is still 5 points ahead with a strong attack.

Comment: @user3671618 yep, that's probably less bad.